# List all binaries a package provides

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, text-processing

This is not a duplicate of listing all files a package provides, i want to list all binaries a certain package provides that are in the standard location for binaries.

I know this can be done with some text processing tool along with `dpkg -L` but i am not very good at those. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
dpkg -L <package_name> | grep -E '/s?bin/'
```

- `dpkg -L` lists all the files provided by a package
- `grep -E '/s?bin/'` searches for files that have `/bin/` or `/sbin/` in their names

This will show all binaries in the standard locations e.g. `/usr/bin/`, `/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/`, `/usr/bin/` or any other location that has `/bin/` in the path.

**Example:**

```
% dpkg -L login | grep -E '/s?bin/'
/usr/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/lastlog
/usr/bin/faillog
/usr/bin/newgrp
/bin/su
/bin/login
/usr/bin/sg
```

---

Or with `sed`:

```
% dpkg -L login | sed -nr '/\/s?bin\// p'
/usr/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/lastlog
/usr/bin/faillog
/usr/bin/newgrp
/bin/su
/bin/login
/usr/bin/sg
```

---

Or with `awk`:

```
% dpkg -L login | awk '/\/s?bin\//'
/usr/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/lastlog
/usr/bin/faillog
/usr/bin/newgrp
/bin/su
/bin/login
/usr/bin/sg
```